# Reading a csv file without formatting cells in R?

Tags: r

[image]

I want to read the CSV file without formatting cells. But R is unable to read the first row properly.

Comment: Hi Gaurav, could you show us a sample of the code you're using to load this file?

Comment: You probably need to remove the first row, or use argument `skip` to skip reading the first row.